# How many permutations with $k$ cycles and $j$ fixed points are there?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, fixed-points, cyclic-decomposition

Suppose I have the numbers $\{1,...,n\}$. I would like to know how many permutations have exactly $k$ cycles and $j$ fixed points.

Comment: Is each of the $j$ fixed points also included in the count of cycles?

Comment: Yes, for example $ \{2,1,3\} $ or $(12) (3)$ in cycle notation has two cycles and one fixed point.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Here the needed concept is [$2-$associated Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedStirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html). First choose your fix points and the remaining is that.

Comment: So in general, first choose $j$ fixed points. Then the remaining $n-j$ should have no fixed points and $k-j$ cycles. So would the answer be ${n \choose j}d_2(n-j,k-j)$ ?

Comment: @Guest Yes, that would be.

Answer (score 3):

By  way   of  enrichment  here  is  an   alternate  formulation  using
combinatorial  classes. What  we present  below has  the  advantage of
permitting  the computation  of  a wide  variety  of statistics.   The
class of permutations with cycles and fixed points marked is

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times \mathcal{V} \times
\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
\\ + \mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the generating function
$$G(z, u, v) = 
\exp\left(uvz + u\frac{z^2}{2} +
u\frac{z^3}{3} +
u\frac{z^4}{4} +
u\frac{z^5}{5} + \cdots\right)$$
which is
$$G(z, u, v) =
\exp\left(uvz-uz+u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

Extracting first the coefficient on $[v^j]$ we obtain

$$\frac{u^j z^j}{j!} 
\exp\left(-uz+u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= \frac{u^j z^j}{j!} 
\exp(-uz) \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

We extract the coefficient on $[u^k]$ in the next step:

$$[u^k] \frac{u^j z^j}{j!} 
\exp(-uz) \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = \frac{z^j}{j!} [u^{k-j}]
\exp(-uz) \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = \frac{z^j}{j!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} \frac{(-1)^q z^q}{q!} 
\frac{1}{(k-j-q)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k-j-q}.$$

To conclude we extract the coefficient on $[z^n]$ (EGF) which yields

$$n! [z^n] \frac{z^j}{j!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} \frac{(-1)^q z^q}{q!} 
\frac{1}{(k-j-q)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k-j-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{j!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} [z^{n-j-q}]
\frac{1}{(k-j-q)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k-j-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{j!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q! \times (n-j-q)!} 
\\ \times (n-j-q)! [z^{n-j-q}]
\frac{1}{(k-j-q)!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{k-j-q}
\\ = n! \frac{1}{j!}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} \frac{(-1)^q}{q! \times (n-j-q)!} 
\left[n-j-q\atop k-j-q\right].$$

This yields the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\choose j}
\sum_{q=0}^{k-j} {n-j\choose q} (-1)^q
\left[n-j-q\atop k-j-q\right].}$$

Note  that we  cannot  simply use  a  Stirling number  $\left[n-j\atop
k-j\right]$ as the second factor  because that would include potential
additional   fixed  points.   The   formula  accounts   for  this   by
inclusion-exclusion (PIE).

The following Maple program shows  how to compute this statistic using
the cycle index $Z(S_n)$ of the symmetric group.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


ENUM :=
proc(n, j, k)
    option remember;
    local part, idx, res;

    res := 0; 

    if n=1 then
        idx := [a[1]];
    else
        idx := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    for part in idx do
        if degree(part) = k and
        degree(part, a[1]) = j then
            res := res + lcoeff(part);
        fi;
    od;

    n!*res;
end;

X := (n, j, k) -> binomial(n,j)
* add(binomial(n-j,q)*(-1)^q
      * abs(stirling1(n-j-q, k-j-q)), q=0..k-j);
```